# apache php server weird logout issue

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, php5, mysql5.5

we have recently moved PHP application on new server,but we are facing weird session out issue on new server, the `session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400` in php.ini but the application goes logout in between site surfing, app was working fine on old server, so we are suspecting issue in sever configuration, this is [phpinfo url](http://www.inspectandcloud.com/phpinfo.php)

can you please advise if we are missing anything in configuration.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe session.cookie_path

Comment: Try configuring a private custom session directory for your application. That can be done with the session_save_path() function or setting the session.save_path configuration directive. where are you storing the session? Is that directory writable by your web user?